# PositionalDataSource returns nothing from Parse Server databse

Tags: android, kotlin, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I'm trying to load `Products` items from a `Parse Server` database using data source type of `PositionalDataSource()`to be able to fetch pages of items while scrolling down.

This what i've done so far :

**My PositionalDataSource() class**

```
class ParsePositionalDataSource: PositionalDataSource<Product>() {

    private fun getQuery() : ParseQuery<Product> {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(Product::class.java).orderByDescending("createdAt")
    }

    override fun loadRange(params: LoadRangeParams, callback: LoadRangeCallback<Product>) {
        val query = getQuery()

        query.limit = params.loadSize
        query.skip = params.startPosition

        val products = query.find()

        callback.onResult(products)
    }

    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Product>) {
        val query = getQuery()

        query.limit = params.requestedLoadSize
        query.skip = params.requestedStartPosition

        val count = query.count()
        val products = query.find()

        callback.onResult(products, params.requestedStartPosition, count)
    }
}
```

And then a data source factory :

```
class ParseDataSourceFactory : DataSource.Factory<Int, Product>() {

    override fun create(): DataSource<Int, Product> {
        return ParsePositionalDataSource()
    }


}
```

And finally my ViewModal class

```
class CategoryTabViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private var pagedListConfig: PagedList.Config = PagedList.Config.Builder().setEnablePlaceholders(true)
        .setPrefetchDistance(5)
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(5)
        .setPageSize(5).build()

    private val sourceFactory = ParseDataSourceFactory()

    private val _productList =  LivePagedListBuilder(sourceFactory, pagedListConfig).build()

    val x = _productList

    //val productList: LiveData<PagedList<Product>> = _productList

    fun getProductList(): LiveData<PagedList<Product>> {
        return _productList
    }
}
```

I've checked if `loadinitial()` returns data by setting a breakpoint after : `val products = query.find()`and yes, `products`contains a list of `Product`

But in my ViewModal, `_productList` it's always null or empty list.

Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution by my self while digging in debugger console output.

I saw a line that says :

```
E/RecyclerView: No layout manager attached; skipping layout
```

And it works just fine after i added the layoutmanager in my RecyclerView

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        ...
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        ... />
```

And the documentation says :

> A LayoutManager is responsible for measuring and positioning item
> views within a RecyclerView as well as determining the policy for when
> to recycle item views that are no longer visible to the user. By
> changing the LayoutManager a RecyclerView can be used to implement a
> standard vertically scrolling list, a uniform grid, staggered grids,
> horizontally scrolling collections and more. Several stock layout
> managers are provided for general use.

And

> When writing a RecyclerView.LayoutManager you almost always want to
> use layout positions whereas when writing an RecyclerView.Adapter, you
> probably want to use adapter positions.

It seems that `RecyclerView.Adapter` needs `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` to be set.